# Java Animation with ActionListener

Tags: java

So I'm trying to draw 2 circles on top of each other (kinda like a snowman) and move the snowman to the right when the user clicks on the "Start" button and stop moving the snowman when the user clicks on the "Stop" button. However, the only thing that I am able to come up with is 2 snowmen drawn next to each other that don't react to the buttons.
Here is what I've come up with:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;


public interface MoveableShape {
    void draw(Graphics2D g);
    void translate(int dx, int dy);

}

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;


public class SnowmanShape implements MoveableShape {

private int x;
private int y;
private int width;

public SnowmanShape(int x, int y, int width){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
}
@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 10); 
    Ellipse2D.Double body = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 11, 10, 10); 
    g2.draw(head);
    g2.draw(body);

}

@Override
public void translate(int dx, int dy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    MoveableShape s;
    public MyPanel (MoveableShape m){
        s = m;
    }
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     { 
         super.paintComponent(g);
         s.draw((Graphics2D)g);
     } 
}

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimationTester {

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int SNOWMAN_WIDTH = 50;
    final static MoveableShape shape = new SnowmanShape(0, 0, SNOWMAN_WIDTH);
    final static JPanel panel = new MyPanel(shape);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(stopButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         final int DELAY = 100;

         // Milliseconds between timer ticks
         Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, translateSnowman());

         startButton.addActionListener(startTimer(t));
         stopButton.addActionListener(stopTimer(t));
    }

    public static ActionListener translateSnowman(){
        return new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                 shape.translate(1, 0);
                 panel.repaint();
            }

        };
    }

        public static ActionListener startTimer(final Timer t){
            return new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                     t.start();
                }

            };
    }

        public static ActionListener stopTimer(final Timer t){
            return new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                     t.stop();
                }

            };
    }
}
```

Could someone please let me know where I went wrong or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I fixed up the AnimationListener so now it doesn't draw 2 snowmans. The snowman still won't move however. I updated the code in the post as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `g2.translate(x, y);` to `SnowmanShape#draw`, before you are painting:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

class SnowmanShape implements MoveableShape {
    static final Color headColor = new Color(0xFFE9C9);
    static final Color bodyColor = new Color(0xEAF6FF);
    static final Color outlineColor = new Color(0x252525);

    int x;
    int y;
    int size;
    Ellipse2D.Double head;
    Ellipse2D.Double body;

    SnowmanShape(int x, int y, int size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        initModel();
    }

    void initModel() {
        head = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, size, size);
        body = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, head.height, size * 1.3d, size * 1.5d);
        body.x -= (body.width - head.width) * (1 / 2d);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2.translate(x, y);
        g2.setColor(headColor);
        g2.fill(head);
        g2.setColor(outlineColor);
        g2.draw(head);
        g2.setColor(bodyColor);
        g2.fill(body);
        g2.setColor(outlineColor);
        g2.draw(body);
    }

    @Override
    public void translate(int dx, int dy) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now the program works perfectly. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I updated the code to show you some fancy snowmen :)

Answer (score 2):

I not an expert on doing things like this, but if I were you I would use the timer to move the objects and then call the paint to repaint the objects in a new position. Therefore, your ShapeIcon class would just keep track of the position of your objects. That probably wasn't all that helpful, so to point you in right direction, you can check out some code in this tutorial [here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/).

Comment: I believe that's what I'm doing since the timer calls translateSnowman() and whether the timer is active or not is determined by the buttons. I also removed the ShapeIcon class in favor of just using SnowmanShape (so I don't have it drawing 2 snowmans)

Comment: What I mean is, that you can override the ActionPerformed part of a Timer. That way, your snowmen will just keep track of where they are. I could give you a section of code if you wanted it to demonstrate.

Comment: I got the answer I was looking for. But thank you for the initial link. As someone who wants to start working on her own game soon, I am sure it will come in handy.